# How to upload image file in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I have created a folder called Images under my wwwroot, how do I upload and save an image file to that folder in MVC? My Controller has an error, please help correct it.

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(TheMobileSuit themobilesuits, IFormFile photo)
{
    DbSet<TheMobileSuit> dbs = _dbContext.TheMobileSuit;
    dbs.Add(themobilesuits);
    themobilesuits.PicFile = Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);

    string fname = "Images/" + themobilesuits.PicFile;
    UploadFile(photo, fname);

    if (_dbContext.SaveChanges() == 1)
        TempData["Msg"] = "New Order Added!";
    else
        TempData["Msg"] = "Error.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private bool UploadFile(IFormFile ufile, string fname)
{
    if (ufile.Length > 0)
    {
        string fullpath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, fname);
        using (var fileStream =
                    new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            ufile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In ASP.NET CORE correct?

Comment: Yes. Please help.

Comment: Please refer this link you can get easily solution https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: _My Controller has error, please help correct it._. What error? which line? You need to provide all details.

Comment: I would advise replacing the image tag with the .net-core tag.  The question isn't specifically about images but it is important that people know it is in .net-core.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close with this.  When I copied your code and filled in the details with what I thought they would probably be I got 2 exceptions.

The first was a directory not found exception.  This was because the images directory did not exist.  Check yours exists and if it doesn't create it.

The second was that TheMobileSuit was an invalid object name.  This is to do with your dbcontext.  Looking at your controller I would guess your dbcontext looks something like this

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    } 
    public DbSet<TheMobileSuit> TheMobileSuit { get; set; }
}
```

For me the code worked once I changed it to this

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    } 
    public DbSet<TheMobileSuit> TheMobileSuits { get; set; }  //note the s at the end 
}
```

My understanding is that most people will give these dbset properties a plural name and I think that once this is followed your code will work fine.